# HTML still caching even after meta tag no caching implementation on Godaddy

Tags: php, html

I am building the following site:  [princeton staffing solutions](http://princetonstaffingsolutions.com).

In it, I use the following `HTML meta tags`

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

Unfortunately, it's still acting as before I added these tags. I make database updates and I need to hard refresh the site to see the changes. **Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?**

I also do this in my PHP before i run the application code:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

I don't know why but **I can't get it to send fresh data**

Do you think it's possible that this issue has to do with Godaddy's Servers? I mean I'm clearly using the meta tags and header calls correctly so my only indication is that its something internal with Godaddy?

I also have removed gzip as Content-Encoding. (`<meta http-equiv="Content-Encoding" content="gzip" >`)

Comment: did you clear your browser's cache?

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes. I think it might have to do with Godaddy's internal server. Do you think thats possible?

Answer (score 0):

3 possible ways :

1. your browser is caching  : remove cache , or even can change browser further can remove internet temporary files.
2. Your ISP is caching : run your website on http://anonymouse.org/. If it's working there it's your ISP. Contact them.
3. godaddy's server caching : You can ask for support.